# Can help me to solve Longest Collatz sequence -14

Tags: python

This is my code

```
def Collatz(n,x,m):    
    if(n%2!=0):
        n=3*n+1
        x=x+1
        Collatz(n,x,m)   
    else:
        n=n/2
        x=x+1
        if(n==1):
            sumlist.append(x)
            print(sumlist)
            print(m)
            m=m+1
            if m==1000000:
                print(max(sumlist),"bye")
                exit();
            Collatz(m,0,m)
        Collatz(n,x,m)            
sumlist=[]

c=2

Collatz(c,0,2)
```

My code is this.But I get some errors after executing it.

```
1]
2
[1, 7]
3
[1, 7, 2]
4
[1, 7, 2, 5]
5
[1, 7, 2, 5, 8]
6
[1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16]
7
[1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3]
8
[1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19]
9
[1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19, 6]
10
[1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19, 6, 14]
11
[1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19, 6, 14, 9]
12
[1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19, 6, 14, 9, 9]
13.....
.....[1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19, 6, 14, 9, 9, 17, 17, 4, 12, 20, 20, 7, 7, 15, 15, 10, 23, 10, 111, 18, 18, 18, 106, 5, 26, 13, 13, 21, 21, 21, 34, 8, 109, 8, 29, 16, 16, 16, 104]
47
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Moratuwa Engineering Study Materials\projecteuler\projecteuler questions.py", line 61, in <module>
    Collatz(c,0,2)
  File "C:\Moratuwa Engineering Study Materials\projecteuler\projecteuler questions.py", line 54, in Collatz
    Collatz(m,0,m)
  File "C:\Moratuwa Engineering Study Materials\projecteuler\projecteuler questions.py", line 36, in Collatz
    Collatz(n,x,m)
  File "C:\Moratuwa Engineering Study Materials\projecteuler\projecteuler questions.py", line 56, in Collatz
```

This code runs until m=47 correctly. Then it shows errors. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You left out the most important part of the error message: what it is. It is `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`. Recursion can't be used as a substitute for iteration in Python since the Python call-stack is easy to overflow. Your code is extremely convoluted and will be difficult to salvage. It might sound harsh, but I recommend throwing it away and writing an iterative approach from the ground up.

Comment: Recursion will only work as long as your collatz chain is not longer than the maximum recusion depth in python (1000). 

As @JohnColeman says, use iteration to be robust to that.

As for your algorithm, my advice would be that regardless of whether you use iteration or recusion, your collatz function should never need to take more than one argument. With that in mind, you can write a recursive function for this in 3 lines... but I'm morally bound not to post a solution to a project Euler problem in a public forum :D

Comment: Yes. Finally I get this.RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. ["Can anyone help me?" is not an easy question to answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341). What exactly do you need help with? For example do you want to just know *why* your code is doing that? If you want to know how to fix it, what have you already tried yourself? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I tried several times with this code @wjandrea .Finally I get this.

Comment: One way: don't use recursion, but do use a dictionary. Once you know that it takes 7 steps to get from 3 to 1, record it: `d[3] = 7`. Then when you encounter 3 again (such as for n = 6) you see that you get from 6 to something in the dictionary in 1 step 6//2 = 3, so at that stage you can enter `d[6] = d[3]+1 = 8` Whenever you process a new value, iterate from that value to a point in the dictionary. At that stage you can enter new dictionary entries for that new value, as well as any other value encountered on the way to a value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A short-term solution would be to manually raise Python's default recursion depth from 1000 to some higher number:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)

def Collatz(n,x,m):  
    ...
```

In the medium term you should move the code inside the `if(n==1):` **into the main loop** of your program. Iteration over `m` doesn't belong in the `Collatz` function, this is why your call stack recurses deeper and deeper and never gets cleaned up.